# spark sql protocol buffer support

Tags: apache-spark-sql, protocol-buffers, apache-spark-dataset

Have been attempting to write against java rdds and datasets and use protocol buffers (v2.5.x) for spark to infer the schema.
However spark fails on protocol buffer field members
Given a proto

```
message FooProto {  
    required string name = 1;
    required string value = 2;
}
```

And an attempt to build a java bean

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestProto implements Serializable {

    private FooProto foobar;

}
```

And then using it spark java

```
 FooProto proto = ParsedHeaderProto.newBuilder()
                                                   .setName("foo")
                                                   .setValue("value")
                                                   .build();
TestProto testProto = TestProto .builder()
                                .foobar(proto)
                                .build();

 JavaRDD<TestProto> rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(Arrays.asList(testProto));
 Dataset<TestProto> dataSet = sqlc.createDataset(rdd.rdd(), Encoders.bean(TestProto.class));
 dataSet.show();
```

throws the following error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot have circular references in bean class, but got the circular reference of class class com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$Descriptor
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$JavaTypeInference$$inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.JavaTypeInference$.inferDataType(JavaTypeInference.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.javaBean(ExpressionEncoder.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.bean(Encoders.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.bean(Encoders.scala)
```

I understand that the javadocs suggest that inference is supported for nested java beans.
My question is whether

1. native support exists already within the spark-framework and is there a glaring error I am missing above that can resolve the problem ?
2. a library exists which adds native support for protocol buffers in spark-sql-datasets ?

The workaround would be to create serializable pojos for every protobuff.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: no, I went with the work-around